# Android Instagram intent to timeline

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram

My question is simple, i want to make an intent to instagram app from my app, but i want to show the timeline (just like we are open the instagram app manually), how can i do this?

This method is working to show an user profile, but i want to show the timeline.

```
private void createInstagramIntent() {

    //Creamos intent de instagram y lanzamos la activity
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/javierjsanchezg");
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    share.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
    startActivity(share);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instagram is mainly a Photo Sharing App and you need to specify the content type. Check the code below. It will open the Instagram App Home Screen of the App is installed in the device and says no app can perform this action if not installed.

> Intent is just a way to connect with other apps and it has minimized
>   control over the other App.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("*/*");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi Android Share intent");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
sharingIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Choose"));
```

Happy Coding..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code to :

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
```

Now as per the user's timeline it depends if it is private or public in order to view it. Hope it helps.

Comment: i don't want to show the user timeline, i want to show my timeline... like we are open instagram if we click the icon. Thanks in advance

Comment: you can just add the link to your profile and it should open.